# How do I allow my app to have drag and drop toolboxes like Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

How do I allow my app to have drag and drop toolboxes like Visual Studio?

Comment: Is this an addon for visual studio?  Built on the Visual Studio shell?  New app?

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place...Stack Overflow won't have your answer...because, the answer, my friend, is blowing in the wind.

Comment: @Beska: +1 for the Bob Dylan reference. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a basic (and free) third party solution to do it look into [DockPanel Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/). But as other said multiple other free or paid solutions exists.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be a third-party component to do this.  Primarily, you are looking for something that provides docking windows on your form (which would more than likely be provided by a control you place on the form which would take up the entire form).

Answer (score 1):

As always, I recommend using the [DevExpress DXperience Components & Tools](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/).  In particular, you want to look into the [Docking Functionality](http://www.devexpress.com/Help/?document=XtraBars/CustomDocument1249.htm) article.

There are free toolkits to do this also, but I've not used any.